# PhantomJS in Ubuntu 11 Server, PNG images look 256-color

Tags: phantomjs

So I'm using PhantomJS on Ubuntu 11 server, and after doing everything I needed to to set it up (including install Xvfb), I have found that web pages captured appear to be saved as 256-color PNG files.

I installed Phantom on Windows and it doesn't have that problem at all. Web pages are full 32-bit color. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Had to run Xvfb with the following params:

`Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x24`

Then execute Phantom. I think there was something wrong with my init file. Thanks @@ariyahidayat :)